# No puedo extraer los datos de un json

Tags: javascript, json, nodejs, angular

Tengo el siguiente json, y necesito extraer el valor de cada key para compararlo contra otros valores,

```
    [ { callerIDName: 'Macon GA',
    callTo: "Cam's Test Pop",
    type: 'InboundCall' },
  { callerIDName: 'Philadelphia Suburban PA',
    callTo: "Cam's Test Pop",
    type: 'InboundCall' },
  { callerIDName: 'La Grange IL',
    callTo: "Cam's Test Pop",
    type: 'InboundCall' } ]
```

Actualmente estoy haciendo

```
var myJSON = JSON.stringify(json['activities'], ['callerIDName', 'callTo', 'type']);

        myJSON = JSON.parse(myJSON);
        console.log(myJSON);

        for (let activity in myJSON) {
            //console.log(activity['callerIDName'])
            console.log(activity); //Esto me imprime 0 1 2 3
        }
```

Lo que deseo es recorrer el json con algun for y poder comparar los valores, si utilizo la linea comentada que dice activity['callerIDName'] me da undefined, soy nuevo en js y no se si hay una mejor manera de hacerlo.

La variable json la estoy llenando de otro metodo que me devuelve el json

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Intenta utilizando `forEach` en lugar de un `for` de esa forma, hasta donde yo tengo entendido el `for` es una implementación de ES6 que aún no está liberada del todo.

No entiendo por que si ya tienes un JSON estas haciendo una cadena y luego regresandolo a JSON... tus motivos has de tener.

Te dejo un ejemplo funcionando, saludos.

```js
var json = [ { callerIDName: 'Macon GA',
    callTo: "Cam's Test Pop",
    type: 'InboundCall' },
  { callerIDName: 'Philadelphia Suburban PA',
    callTo: "Cam's Test Pop",
    type: 'InboundCall' },
  { callerIDName: 'La Grange IL',
    callTo: "Cam's Test Pop",
    type: 'InboundCall' } ];
    
var myJSON = JSON.parse( JSON.stringify( json ) );

myJSON.forEach( (activity) => {
  console.log( activity.callerIDName );
});
```

**Actualizo**
Según Mozilla el for de esa forma es una mala idea iterar arreglos (En caso tuyo), funciona mejor iterar sobre objetos

> Aunque pueda ser tentador utilizar esto como opción para iterar sobre
>   un Array, es una mala idea.

[For in](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/JavaScript/Referencia/Sentencias/for...in)

Comment: Hola, recuerda que el método `forEach()` es propio de la clase `Array` de Javascript. Sería bueno que aclarases que el O.P. no tiene un JSON persé, sino un array cuyos elementos son JSON. Saludos

Comment: Gracias, efectivamente con ese forEach me sirvió perfectamente.

Answer (score 2):

Tu JSON es un *array*, no un *objeto*. Por lo tanto, [la forma `for( ... in ... )` **no es la adecuada**](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/JavaScript/Referencia/Sentencias/for...in): además de los índices numéricos (y de forma no necesariamente ordenada), recorrerá todas las propiedades que tú hayas definido.

Dispones de varias alternativas para recorrer los [*array*: `foreach( )`, `map( )`, `reduce( )`](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/JavaScript/Referencia/Objetos_globales/Array/prototype) ... o la más clásica: un simple `while( )`.

A falta de mas datos, escojo esta última:

```
var val, idx = -1;
while( ( val = myJSON[++idx] ) ) {
  console.log( val['callerIDName'] );
}
```

Comment: Gracias por la ayuda, con el forEach me sirvió perfectamente. Slds